# Proper adjective for an addictive TV series

Tags: word-choice

Can I use *Crazy addictive* for a TV series which I'm being hooked up?

Like: This TV show is not as *crazy addictive* as that TV show.

Comment: You could be mistaken in the slang usage of *crazy*. It is generally used adjectivally to a **positive/ emphasizing** effect, not negatively as in the example. "This TV show is crazy addictive!" would be fine in slang. On the other hand, "not as crazy addictive" contradicts the emphasis.

Comment: *Highly* addictive? Unless you think speaking correct English will give you strange looks from your friends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grammatically speaking, as others have pointed out, it should be [**crazily** addictive](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22crazily%20addictive%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) - but the more common expression (in Google Books) is actually...

> [**insanely** addictive](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22insanely%20addictive%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1).

I think younger speakers increasingly use *crazy* as a general-purpose intensifier equivalent to *very*, so they don't necessarily see anything ungrammatical in OP's usage. By contrast, you'll very rarely hear anything referred to as ?***insane*** addictive.

Comment: Ah yes, Google Books, that fine resource not yet available in my country. When region coding comes to literature. Let's make it unavailable to all US Immigrants from other countries. You're not being consistent and thorough, Google.

Comment: @Henrik: That's a bummer. Can you maybe get around it by going through a proxy server? (just don't ask me how you do that, 'cos I haven't got a clue! :)

Answer (score 2):

*Crazily addictive* would be the more correct form, adjectives are modified by adverbs, not by other adjectives.

You could use *crazy addictive* very informally, where it would be interpreted as a deliberate bending of the rules to produce a slangy-sounding phrase. If you aren't confident you know exactly why it's bending the rules though, you're probably better of not using it. The trick is to sound like someone who knows it's not really allowed, but did it anyway, rather than someone who just doesn't know.

Comment: And I wouldn't use it when comparing two shows.  It'd be used to say that one particular show is *very* addictive, i.e.,  *That show is crazy addictive!*

Comment: @Jim Yeah, but "okay, it's addictive, but it's not crazy addictive like the last season was".

Comment: Yes, that is subtly different than the OP's comparison.

Answer (score 1):

*Crazy*, while usually an adjective, can be used as an adverb modifying an adjective in the manner you suggest, as in this [example](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/crazy)

> I bought some crazy good stuff there.

This usage is very colloquial.

Answer (score 1):

"Crazy addictive" is fine in the US and used all the time. But it is slang. So if your register is informal, it's fine. However, the best way to express your feeling is by just using the word "addictive". " This TV show is not as addictive as that one."

Answer (score 0):

The formal expression for the idea you wish to convey might be *intensely attractive* or metaphorically *extremely seductive*.